# Unable to start Spring MVC application in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I am developing an MVC web application in java using spring framework and maven tool using Spring Tool Suite.

I am getting the following error when i am running my application.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method   "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/view/NewFile_jsp, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager used in the signature
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.NewFile_jsp._jspInit(NewFile_jsp.java:32)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

`Jan 23, 2015 12:55:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with     path [/MyMsit] threw exception [java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint  violation: when resolving method    "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/s ervlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader  (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class,  org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/view/NewFile_jsp, and the class loader (instance  of java/net/URLClassLoader) for the method's defining class,  org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class  objects for the type org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager used in the signature]  with root cause
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method     "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/view/NewFile_jsp, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager used in the signature
```

Contents of pom.xml are

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>net.mymsit</groupId>
<artifactId>MyMsit</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>MyMsit</name>
<description>Complete Course portal for MSIT Course</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Web -->
    <jsp.version>2.3.1</jsp.version>
    <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>


    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

    <!-- Logging -->

    <slf4j.version>1.7.10</slf4j.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <!-- Other Web dependencies -->

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Boot Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.21.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.linkedin</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.linkedin.zookeeper-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.linkedin</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.linkedin.util-groovy</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

contents of web.xml are as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<welcome-file-list>

<welcome-file>NewFile.html</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>
<display-name>MyMsit</display-name>

<!--
    - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
    - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!--
    - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I can't understand the error. Could anyone help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Looking at your dependencies I would say they are a mess. Are you trying to use Spring Boot or not? Your project is confusing...

Comment: in STC do i need to mention spring dependencies explicitly in pom.xml?

Comment: This is not specific to STS or the IDE. If you are using Maven to manage your dependencies in your project, you have to deal with them in your pom.xml file, independent of the IDE you are using to implement your project. STS will parse the pom.xml file and use Maven to resolve those dependencies. And your error looks very much like there is a dependency issue somewhere. I would recommend to start with a clean and fresh Spring Boot app (using the Spring Guides at https://spring.io/guides, for example). You can use them in STS directly as well, if you want to.

Comment: I believe this is a dependencies issue with your environment. As others have stated first make sure that you are not pulling duplicate jars.

I was getting the same thing on a project with Eclipse Luna and tomcat. I was sure that my decencies were correct. As it turned out for my case it was Eclipse groovy plug-in that caused this issue.

One thing you can try; if on windows; is download Process Monitor and track what’s been called by javaw.exe. 

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

In reference to Shrikant's post - sort of.

When using Tomcat, you definitely do not want to include Tomcat's jar files in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

The jars are coming from your Maven dependencies on Spring Boot.
Specify that the spring-boot jars are provided in your pom, like so

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
```

This caused me a bit of aggravation, until I looked at the expanded pom's Dependency Hierarchy and saw where the tomcat jars were coming from.  Once I changed the scope to provided instead of compile on the spring-boot dependencies, my pages loaded just fine.

Shrikant -> Nothing against your answer really, I just don't care to delete jars from my lib directory and then build a war, when I can just clean, package, install, and deploy all in one go, clicking one button.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same problem, but i got the solution. 
If you are using Tomcat server, then You must not put tomcat's jar files into WEB-INF/lib. Tomcat already has thoses classes, and they must be loaded by the root tomcat classloader, not by the web-app classloader.
So check your WEB-INF/lib folder and delete all the tomcat's jar.(e.g: tomcat-api-8.0.0-RC1.jar, tomcat-juli-8.0.0-RC1.jar,  tomcat-util-8.0.0-RC1.jar, tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.0-RC1.jar).

Answer (score 0):

instead of configuring in web.xml, use a class which implements SpringBootServletInitializer,

Comment: You need to explain your answer in more detail